# The estimator of variance of linear regression targets

Tags: regression, machine-learning, estimation, standard-deviation, estimators

In Section 3.2 of the book *The elements of Statistical Learning* (2ed), I read the text:

Typically one estimates the variance $\sigma^2$ by
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N-p-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-\hat{y}_i^2)
$$

where $N$ is the number of training data, each has dimension $p+1$ (where the first coordinates are 1). $y_i$ is the target, all the $y_i$s are uncorrelated and have constant variance $\sigma^2$. All the input $x_i$ are fixed (non-random).

My question is, how can we derive and obtain this estimator?